# complete manifolds in product metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complete-spaces

> Let $M=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be equipped with the warped
> product metric $g(x,\theta)=dx^2+e^{-x^2}h_\theta$ , where $h_\theta$
> is standard metric on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ . Prove that $(M,g)$ is a
> complete Riemannian manifold .

Using Hopf-Rinow , it is enough to prove metrical completeness . So we choose two points $x,y\in M$ . Denote $x=(x_1,\theta_1)$ and $y=(x_2,\theta_2)$  and $d_g$ as geodesic distance in $(M,g)$ . Then clearly $$d_g(x,y)=|x_1-x_2|+d_h(\theta_1,\theta_2)\geq|x_1-x_2|$$ But I'm not able to show the reverse inequality in order to show $M$ is metrically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ , which is complete .

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Your method of proof is flawed, an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold is never going to be metrically equivalent to $\mathbb R$. But there are still plenty of metricallly complete $n$-dimensional manifolds nonetheless. On top of that, your formula for $d_g(x,y)$ is false; $d_g(x,y)$ is the infimum of path lengths with endpoints $x,y$, and need not be equal to the sum you wrote.

Comment: I see , my bad ! Can you give a possible approach to show the completeness ?